# Apache reverse proxy - URL without / is refused

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I use reverse proxy to show backend server content for a subdomain.
The subdomain.mydomain.com (server A) should display content of server with IP 123.123.123.123 port 1111 (server B).

Virtual host of subdomain.mydomain.com (server A):

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName subdomain.mydomain.com

SSLEngine on
SecAuditEngine On
RewriteEngine On
SSLProxyEngine on
ProxyPreserveHost On
LogLevel warn

<Directory />
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Location />
    ProxyPass https://123.123.123.123:1111
    ProxyPassReverse https://123.123.123.123:1111
</Location>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

SSLProtocol             all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder     on
SSLVerifyClient none
SSLVerifyDepth 1

SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/cert.site/chain_wildcard_site_combined.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/cert.site/key_wildcard_site.key
 
SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

</VirtualHost>                                  
</IfModule>
```

Virtual host of 123.123.123.123:1111 (server B):

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost 123.123.123.123:1111>
        DocumentRoot /srv/www/site/htdocs

SSLEngine on
RewriteEngine On
SSLProxyEngine on
ProxyPreserveHost On
LogLevel warn

<Location "/">
   Require ip 222.222.222.222
</Location>

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory /srv/www/site/htdocs>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog /srv/www/site/log/error.log
CustomLog /srv/www/site/log/access.log combined
CustomLog /srv/www/site/log/ssl_request_log \
            "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

SSLProtocol             all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder     on
SSLVerifyClient none
SSLVerifyDepth 1

SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/cert.site/chain_wildcard_site_combined.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/cert.site/key_wildcard_site.key

        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

If I load URL:
https://subdomain.mydomain.com/dir/

it loads successfully.

If I load URL (without trailing slash):
https://subdomain.mydomain.com/dir

it results error page: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

**EDIT1:**

I execute command:

```
curl -IL https://subdomain.mydomain.com/dir
```

and I get this result:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Mon, 23 Aug 2021 13:45:13 GMT
Server: Apache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains
Location: https://subdomain.mydomain.com:1111/dir/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

curl: (7) Failed to connect to subdomain.mydomain.com port 1111: Connection refused
```

**EDIT2:**

I added trailing slash

```
<Location />
    ProxyPass https://123.123.123.123:1111/
    ProxyPassReverse https://123.123.123.123:1111/
</Location>
```

But I still get the **Connection refused** error.

Any idea why is it resulting error, when trailing slash is missing?

Thanks!

Comment: `https://subdomain.mydomain.com:1111/dir` - This URL should not contain the `:1111` port number. That alone could cause the ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error since server A is presumably only listening on port 443 (and perhaps port 80). What response do you get when you remove the port from that URL?

Comment: Thanks! It was a typo. I modified it in OP: https://subdomain.mydomain.com/dir

Answer (score 0):

Since you used `ProxyPreserveHost ON`, your `ProxyPassReverse` should be `ProxyPassReverse https://subdomain.mydomain.com:1111/` because this is the Location: header your backend is producing that you need the frontend to fixup.

The backend unfortunately sees no port in the Host: header and picks the port of the local connection. It is a problem that only happens when the default port is used on the frontend + ProxyPreserveHost.  ServerName with an explicit port :443 might help on the backend.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use port 1111 for SSL - it MUST be 443 (modern certificates and CORS do not work or accept different ports)